# Boston's "Spaces of constant rank matrices over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, sagemath, magma-cas

Let’s recall what is spaces of matrices of constant rank, that is, in spaces of matrices in which every nonzero matrix has the same rank. The case is, i’m reading journal by NIGEL BOSTON titled “SPACES OF CONSTANT RANK MATRICES OVER GF(2)”, the same with this question’s title. In the journal’s abstract, it said that, “for each n, we cconsider there exist an (n+1)- dimensional space of n by n matrices GF(2) in which nonzero matrix has rank n-1. Examples are given for n=3,4, and 5, together with evidence for the conjecture that none exist for n>8". The problem is, NIGEL BOSTON used MAGMA to show that there are exactly 1176 such spaces for n=3. And under conjugation by GL(3,2), these fall into 12 orbits. A basis for a representative of each orbit is given by:

[image: orbit under conjugation GL(3,2)]

I got task from my lecture to make simulation for it (using MAGMA), but we know that there is no trial/free version of MAGMA, so i remember about SAGE, is SAGE be able to do such thing? And if yes, how i do that (the code for SAGE), otherwise if not, is there another program similar to MAGMA (open source or free) and possible to do the simulation? Hope you help me, thanks you so much!

Note: this is link for the journal

[journal link](http://repository.uwyo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1354&context=ela)

Comment: Surely your lecturer has an idea of what tools you can use for the simulation at your institute, so why ask us? Anyway, you are given basis elements for the spaces, and you can easily generate 168 elements of GL(3,2). Even by hand! I don't understand what you are asking. The list you posted comes with a blueprint for generating those 1176 spaces.

Comment: I mean, it does not sound like you are asked to verify that Nigel Boston's list is correct. You can just use it. If I misunderstood then I apologize.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Just verify that the orbits are of the lengths shown in the paper?